# How to install nix on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, nix

I'm trying to install Nix on Google colab because of a Python package that has dependencies outside of pip.

The installation seems to work but commands such as `nix-shell` or `nix-daemon` do not work. It seems like there is something about starting a new terminal before using Nix but I do not know how to do that with google colab.

[Edit: cross posted here https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-install-nix-on-google-colab/29000/5]

Answer (score 1):

You need to source the nix daemon after installing nix before you can run nix commands.

You can try find this in the nix store or in `\$HOME/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh`

Comment: Hi thank you I am not familiar with the term sourcing but chatgpt told me that you are asking me to execute the command  `source "$HOME/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh"` is that correct ?

Comment: If the nix daemon is located there, then yes. 

If it's not, I'd look in the nix store. You can find it using the find command.

Comment: In a google colab cell (`%%shell` is used to consider the cell to be a shell command) `%%shell

source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh

which nix-shell` seems to work with but the package that I want to install does not but that might be a separate problem. Do you have any code you would suggest to check whether the installation worked?

Comment: I tried ```%%shell

source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh

nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m"``` and that also seems to work so maybe the problem  is the installation of the package but I cannot confirm that the installation works so although I did upvote, I can not really accept without being sure.

Comment: @userrandrand, something like `nix-shell -p package_you_want --run 'program-from-the-package-you-want --version'`, maybe? Obviously, this depends on details of what you're using Nix to install.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hi I tried `nix-shell
-p python37Packages.scikits-odes -p python37Packages.numpy
--run "python3"`  according to the instructions of https://scikits-odes.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#using-nix but I got a long error report. Something about `undefined variable 'python37Packages'` but the error source seems to be deep so i suppose the code is doing something

Comment: It does seem like the code by Edward is working but it bothers me to accept without being sure. I will accept the answer if anyone suggests a well-known package to try and that it works.

Comment: Are you sure the active nixpkgs channel is one that still provides Python 3.7? On my phone and can't check, but I thought they dropped that one after it left its support window.

Comment: From your comments, it looks like nix is working.

You can try the following to confirm: `%%shell  source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh && nix help`

I suggest you make a new question asking how to get the package you want.